# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function ReactJS + Recoil

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

I am using ReactJs and Recoil. When exporting an atom and importing it into App.js, I get a TypeError: Object (...) is not a function, what is the problem?

atoms.js:

```
    import atom from 'recoil';

    export const textState = atom({
    key: 'textState', // unique ID (with respect to other atoms/selectors)
    default: '', // default value (aka initial value)
  });
```

App.js:

```
import {
  useRecoilState, atom
} from 'recoil';
import { textState } from "./atoms"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might need to destruct `atom` from the recoil library

Try changing your import to look like this:

`import { atom } from 'recoil'`

More information in their docs:
https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/getting-started

Learn more about destructuring in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment